# What is the feature of -[NSURL isFileReferenceURL]?

Tags: nsurl, file-reference-url

The method `-isFileReferenceURL` is define on `NSURL` class but I can't figure out what this method is. I thought this determines whether the URL points actual file or not, but it isn't. It returns `NO` even when the file exist. The manual says just

```
isFileReferenceURL Returns whether the URL is a file reference URL.

- (BOOL)isFileReferenceURL Return Value YES if the URL is a file reference URL; otherwise, NO.

Availability Available in iOS 5.0 and later. (Symbol is present in iOS 4, but performs no operation.) Declared In NSURL.h
```

What is this method? What is the *file reference URL*? When does this method returns `YES`?

Comment: Just a note, see [`-[NSURL fileReferenceURL]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000301-SW27) method for more informations:

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A file reference URL is a special URL that refers directly to a file, rather than to "whatever file is at this path". This allows it to still point to the file if the user moves it, for example, which is very useful. You can create a file reference URL by calling the `-fileReferenceURL` method on any regular file URL.

Comment: Looks like ***hard link***.

Comment: File reference URLs are not implemented using hard links

Comment: @Itachi — It's more like an inode or a key in a cache table. It's a unique identifier for a file system item. It is recalculated every time the drive is mounted. It looks like: `file:///.file/id=6571367.8602676692`. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl/1408631-filereferenceurl?language=objc

Answer (score -6):

Try using `isFileURL`.  There's a difference between a "File Reference URL" and a "URL that points at a File". ;)

Comment: As the OP's question asked: *What is that difference?*